# Delete all but 1 latest file bash

Tags: bash

I've got directory with files like:

```
dump_2014_12_21_1001.7z
dump_2014_12_21_1122.7z
dump_2014_12_21_1207.7z
dump_2014_12_21_1334.7z
```

Number of files may be different.

I need to write bash script to delete all files except newest one?

Comment: num=$(ls /tmp/ | wc -l)
    num=$((num-1))
    (ls -lt /tmp/ | tail -n $num;ls) | sort|uniq -u|xargs rm

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use that `num=$(ls /tmp/ | wc -l) num=$((num-1)) (ls -lt /tmp/ | tail -n $num;ls) | sort|uniq -u|xargs rm` you posted.

Your filenames are very glob-friendly, you don't need to sort them again.
Here's a better solution:

```
unset oldfile
for file in *.7z; do
  [[ $oldfile ]] && rm "$oldfile"
  oldfile=$file
done
```

Comment: Or: `shopt -s nullglob; files=( *.7z ); (( ${#files[@]}>1 )) && rm -- "${files[@]:1}"`. Provided there are not too many files.